# Has this Banach algebra been studied?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, function-spaces

Given $\Omega$ as  $[0,1]^n$ or the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can consider the algebra of complex valued polynomials with pointwise multiplication and its closure with respect to the norm

$$
\|p\| = \|p\|_\infty + \sum_{k=1}^n\left\| \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_k} \right\|_1.
$$

I am wondering if this Banach algebra has been studied. If so, does it have a common name, and what are some resources that I can read about it?

Comment: What multiplication operation?  Pointwise multiplication? What is your bound for $\|\nabla(pq)\|_1$ ?

Comment: As you probably know, for $n=1$ this is (possibly up to some renorming) the Banach algebra of absolutely continuous functions AC[0,1]. Some years ago I was looking for higher-dimensional analogues and I think one candidate was the example you describe, but I don't recall seeing it explicitly defined and studied as a Banach algebra

Comment: @GeraldEdgar The definition seems to make sense to me: is your point that the norm defined above might not be submultiplicative?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the norm. It should be submultiplicative now. As for the operation, it is pointwise multiplication. I'll edit that in too.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me for asking this but... why is this particular function algebra a object of study? Does it - for example - occur naturally in some application, or do you have reason to believe it will have properties very different from the usual $C^k$, $C^{k,\alpha}$, $W^{k,p}$ algebras which do? ($C^k$ maybe less so than the others). This comment isn't meant as any kind of criticism btw - I'm just curious :)

Comment: (and I'm certainly not suggesting that things which don't have obvious connections to applications aren't worthy of study)

Comment: @DCM the background of my research consists of operators that have an $AC[a,b]$ functional calculus and their integral representations. Trying to generalise the theory to compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with an appropriate class of functions is why I was wondering if this object has been studied.